# Black Laptop Screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an issue where the screen on an HP HDX16 laptop is black.

The information I've gathered so far is:

- It appears to have happened after an update, so it could be driver-related (NVIDIA 130M)
- The laptop screen is black
- External monitors don't seem to register either
- During bootup, the BIOS also won't appear
- The computer IS on, as shared files can be accessed from another computer.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no BIOS pre-boot display, then its not a windows problem. It's likely a hardware problem.
Googleing HDX16 and "No display" shows a few people reporting a similar situation where the cable of the LCD is broken/intermittent. This is the very tiny cable from the motherboard thru the LCD hindge up to the LCD. The threads seem to suggest that the LCD cable of this model is susceptible to breaking at this point. One person mentions they can get the display to return occasionally by various closing/slightly twisting of the LCD cover.
[Here's one HP thread.](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video/HP-HDX-16-Display-Not-Working/td-p/1436797)
[And here's another.](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video/No-display-out-of-HP-hdx-16-1050ef-premium/td-p/1041937)

Comment: I thought this could be the case, however I don't think this would explain why an external display also won't work.

Comment: True, a cable problem should only effect the laptop LCD. I have seen a similar problem with an IBM Thinkpad where some of the Graphics chip solder connectors to the motherboard were faulty. Pressing on the GPU chip could get the graphics to display again. If you remove the keyboard, you can try that experiment. With the thinkpad, the keyboard was flexible enough so pressing near the G-H-B-N keys could temporarily flash the display. If that turns out to be the problem, search for "motherboard reflow".